# How do I set a proxy server when using dispatch.Http?

Tags: scala

My code looks something like this:

```
  val r = :/(srv, 80) <:< Map("Cookie" -> "Scale=Scout%20Pro")
  implicit val http = new Http with NoLogging
  val rBeg = r / "endSessionRedirect.do"
  http(rBeg <<? Map("r" -> to) >|)
```

It works properly, but now I need to route it through a proxy.  How can I do this?

Comment: mmmmh bould you explain further because it is not clear to me where the proxy should come in the game. Do you want something that is able to make url rewriting in the Request directly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it was easier that I though, it is Java underneath after all, so passing the Java proxy options works:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8001
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried this with 0.11.0 and it doesn't work. I also tried passing them as JVM arguments without success. Any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: This should not be accepted. Dispatch ignores these settings as it use Netty under the hood and Netty ignores it: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1133

Answer (score 3):

You can set a proxy server on the `Req` object directly in Dispatch 0.11 like:

```
val r = :/(srv, 80).setProxyServer(new ProxyServer("localhost", 8000)) <:< Map("Cookie" -> "Scale=Scout%20Pro")
```

Based on my testing (with v0.11.0), Dispatch completely ignores the JVM proxy options.